# Mongodb insert object into an array which is inside another attribute

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongodb-update

I need to update a document by inserting a bid into the Bid array which is part of Bid. An example document is below:

```
{
  "_id" : "1044300051",
  "Bids" : {
    "Bid" : [
        {
            "Bidder" : {
                "_id" : "pickford25",
                "_Rating" : 255,
                "Location" : "ANIME PARADISE",
                "Country" : "USA"
            },
            "Time" : "Dec-07-01 15:02:54",
            "Amount" : 1.12
        },
        {
            "Bidder" : {
                "_id" : "arlnwtkwsk@aol.com",
                "_Rating" : 61,
                "Location" : "ARCADE, NEW YORK",
                "Country" : "USA"
            },
            "Time" : "Dec-09-01 15:02:54",
            "Amount" : 1.25
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are some of the queries I have attempted:

```
db.items.update({_id: "1678348584"}, {$set: {Bids: "Bid[]"}},{$push: {"Bids.Bid": {"Amount":1000}}});
db.items.update({_id: "1678348584"}, {$push: {"Bids": [{"Amount":1000}]}});
```

The specific _id I am trying to update in the above examples has "Bids" set to null initially

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. To access a nested array you'll have to use `Bids.Bid`. Your query should be something like

```
db.items.update({_id: "1678348584"}, {$push: {"Bids.Bid": {"Amount":1000}}});
```

Comment: That gives me this error:

    WriteResult({
     "nMatched" : 0,
     "nUpserted" : 0,
         "nModified" : 0,
     "writeError" : {
      "code" : 16837,
      "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: Bids.$.Bid"
     }
    })

Comment: I just saw that. Updated the query.

Comment: That gives this error: 
    "code" : 16837,
      "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (Bids of Bids.Bid) to traverse the element ({Bids: null})"

—The specific ID I am trying to update has Bids set to null initially

Comment: well, you didn't mention that in your question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that would affect the answer. I'll edit the question.